# function with return array not working. php

Tags: php, arrays, function

Ok Can you guys help me here. This is the function. It gets 3 aurguments, and it returns an array. it converts gregorian date to persian date. It's in Includes/dateConvert.php

```
    public static function toJalali($g_y, $g_m, $g_d)
{
    $g_days_in_month = array(31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31);
    $j_days_in_month = array(31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 29);
    $gy = $g_y-1600;
    $gm = $g_m-1;
    $gd = $g_d-1;
    $g_day_no = 365*$gy+self::div($gy+3, 4)-self::div($gy+99, 100)+self::div($gy+399, 400);
    for ($i=0; $i < $gm; ++$i)
        $g_day_no += $g_days_in_month[$i];
    if ($gm>1 && (($gy%4==0 && $gy%100!=0) || ($gy%400==0)))
        $g_day_no++;
    $g_day_no += $gd;
    $j_day_no = $g_day_no-79;
    $j_np = self::div($j_day_no, 12053);
    $j_day_no = $j_day_no % 12053;
    $jy = 979+33*$j_np+4*self::div($j_day_no, 1461);
    $j_day_no %= 1461;
    if ($j_day_no >= 366) {
        $jy += self::div($j_day_no-1, 365);
        $j_day_no = ($j_day_no-1)%365;
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < 11 && $j_day_no >= $j_days_in_month[$i]; ++$i)
        $j_day_no -= $j_days_in_month[$i];
    $jm = $i+1;
    $jd = $j_day_no+1;
    return array($jy, $jm, $jd);
}
```

and div is a simple dividing function

```
private static function div($a, $b)
{
    return (int) ($a / $b);
}
```

now When I write something like below the code doesn't do anything.

```
<?php
require ("Includes/dateConvert.php");
$yy = 1989;
$mm = 8;
$dd = 31;
echo $yy.$mm.$dd;
echo "<br><br>";
$jj = toJalali($yy, $mm, $dd);
echo $jj[0].$jj[1].$jj[2];
?>
```

What am I doing wrong? thank you.

Comment: `public static function` is at least a member of class. Calling `$jj = toJalali` means that you call some other function.

Comment: Oh you are right. So I have to exclude the function individually and use it right?

Comment: Calling static function is like `ClassName::MethodName`

Comment: Thank you. Actually I don't need the whole code to work, just the function is enough, so if copy the code and include it in my php file will it work? I guess I have to change the self parts as well as it is referring to the class.

Comment: Yes it did work, Thank you just post your answer down so I can choose it as solution.

Comment: You can also; delete `public static` instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see your function is defined like

```
public static function toJalali
```

It means that this function as a method of some class. I don't know name of, let's call it `ClassName`. As this function is `static` it can be called without creating class instance like:

```
ClassName::toJalali()
```

Removing `public static` as @EliasNicolas advised will not work as function will still be a method of class.

If you want to use function as standalone function - then you should cut/copy function code out of class and, yes, remove `public static`. So it will be just

```
function toJalali()
```

outside of any class codes.